# Easiest way to send data from the Intel Edison to Cordova app over BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, intel-edison

I have an Intel Edison with Ubilinux and am trying to send (stream) data to a Cordova app over BLE.  Are both SPP and GATT options (iOS and/or Android)?  What steps would most easily achieve this?

Comment: A bit of context would help. What have you tried already ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any standard way of streaming data in BLE.  You just set characteristics and that can be used to create a streaming effect.

A similar question was asked on the [Nordic forums](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/71/is-there-a-serial-port-profile-for-ble/).  They reference a rather vague discussion on how to create a BLE profile.

You might also look at MicroChip's [MLDP](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m837813.aspx).  They manage do send a few kB/sec over BLE.